# Questions/answers with legal issues

Tags: discussion

What do we want to do about questions where answers might fall afoul of legal or regulatory issues?  For example, [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/203/high-power-wireless-network-adapter) asks for a 3-watt Wifi adapter.  In most countries, a 3W EIRP radio is far more powerful than you can use without a license.

Wifi is probably the area where this is going to come up the most, since regulations (permissible channels, permissible power, permissible antennas, etc.) vary greatly between countries.

Comment: Here is somewhat of a precedent on another site: [Are questions about a marijuana garden allowed?](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/a/338/2441)

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8492/should-an-answer-that-encourages-illegal-activity-be-marked-as-offensive)

Answer (score 10):

**In general:** it's not our job to enforce the law.

That means, just because something *might* be illegal *somewhere*, we shouldn't delete it. Instead, if you think the OP might be affected by it, leave a comment saying

> FYI: What you're asking for might violate law X in Y jurisdiction.

and that should sort the issue - they can take their own decisions.

**However** - if something comes up that's either very clearly illegal everywhere, or something comes up that we decide we don't want to allow, we can and should delete it.

[As Shog9 explains](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24070513#24070513), some communities decide to disallow questions on a particular topic, either because the issues surrounding the topic are complicated, or because they don't want to be seen to support the issue. That's fine, we can do that. For example, Arqade disallows questions about piracy, and Super User disallows questions on Hackintosh.

If something's **actively harmful** to the community, or we decide we don't want it, then it gets deleted. If it's just a case that it's sometimes illegal, a comment will do.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with you here, I have to say I don't see a legitimate reason to remove these kinds of questions. The wifi adapter may very well be intended for use in a country where it isn't allowed, but we have to recognize that OP's intentions for using this product are left unstated. This basically comes down to the fact that there isn't probable cause to remove it.

Note that if the OP's intentions *were* stated, I'd say we should definitely remove this question.